# Illegal character in query at index where I'm having '>' greater sign-- salesforce

Tags: api, salesforce

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 144:

```
https://h-cpq-develop-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id,TracedEntityId+from+TraceFlag+Where+ExpirationDate>=2016-11-23T13:13:18.000-0800+and+TracedEntityId='00541000000oTFVAA2'
```

If I replace '>' with '=' works fine.. problem is the greater sign.

Thanks in advance!